# how to declare in manifest file when creating database with name student and exactly where to declare

Tags: android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.studentdatabase"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
<compatible-screens></compatible-screens>

<application

    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
     android:name=".MainActivity"
     android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

    </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    </application>

    </manifest>
```

how to declare in manifest file when creating database with name student and       exactly where to declare ,if anybody knows the answer for this question please answer

Comment: no need to add database file in Manifest

Comment: there no need to add database class in you manifest file ...

Comment: actually my app is crashing what i have to do

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add the name of your database on your manifest file. You can add database name on strings.xml and just use that string where your database will be created.

Comment: actually my app is crashing what i have to do